# Convert Java jar file in to cpp

Tags: java, c++, qt, symbian

I have a java code and created a jar file.
I need to create an Qt application. Can I use this code in that application?
Please help me how can i use that jar file.

Thanks,
Nagaraju.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the capabilities of GCC/GCJ (see http://gcc.gnu.org/ ). IF it's a good idea is a whole other story, and depends on what you have, and what you're trying to accomplish. It should be doable to link SO's created with GCJ in QT applications, but I seriously wonder if you are not better off using either C++ or Java, but not mixing them

Comment: actually i wrote a logic in java with using Map, list and String fonctionalities that i am unable to convert into c++. that's why i need some conver.

Comment: Can i write Qt application in java?

Comment: IMHO, QMap, QString, QList are as powerful as their JDK counterpart. Are you sure you can't do the conversion. Edit: Qt Jambi is Qt for Java

Answer (score 0):

If your Java code takes input from stdin or some file and writes output to stdout or some file, then the easiest way is to fork java to run that jar, and parse the output in your Qt code.

Things other than that, you'll need to be a bit specific.  Something like "my Java code does painting the screen".

Comment: Acually i have four classes. it doesn't have any screens. it has some logic and it asks one string in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use SWT or Swing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gcj [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) to compile the java code to library and simply call the functions of the java code from your C code.

Comment: can you tell about 'gcj'. how to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your jar file in your Qt application. I've done exactly this myself.

One way is to use the [JNI Invocation API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502). This is part of the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/), which makes it feasible but not pleasant to access Java APIs from C++.

A much more pleasant approach is to use [CodeMesh JunC++ion](http://www.codemesh.com/products/junction/), which wraps the Java APIs in C++ classes. This is a great product, if you can afford it.

If you have very little Java code, it may be easier to port it to C++.

Comment: I can't able to download the CodeMEsh junC++ion. can you help me?